# AS3 hitTestObject==false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a life bar in my game and whenever the minion doesn't catch the bananas, the life bar decreases. It works fine, but the problem is that the life bar decreases before it touches the ground. Do I need to add another hitTest in the ground and have it in an && statement?
Main program:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var leftKey:Boolean;
var rightKey:Boolean;
var upKey:Boolean;
var downKey:Boolean;
var jump:Boolean = false;
var xvelocity:int = 9;
var yvelocity:int = 3;
var gravity:Number = 7;


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVelocity);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyUp);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyDown);

  function changeVelocity(evt:Event){
        moveMinion();
        yvelocity += gravity;
    }

    function moveMinion(){

        if (leftKey == true){
           sideMinion.x -= xvelocity;
            sideMinion.left();

        }
        if (rightKey == true){
            sideMinion.x += xvelocity;
            sideMinion.right();
        }

    }

    function checkKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = true;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = true;
        }

    }

    function checkKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = false;
        }

    }

    btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeItFall);

    function makeItFall(e:MouseEvent){



    var numBananas = 6;
    var theBananas: Array = new Array();
    theBananas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numBananas; i++) {
    var aBanana: banana = new banana();
    theBananas.push(aBanana);
    btnStart.visible=false;
    aBanana.y=100;
    theBananas[i].setSpot(Math.random()*450,Math.random()*200);
    theBananas[i].setSpeed((Math.random()), 1);
    stage.addChild(aBanana);

}   

var health: Number= 100;
var healthPercent: Number= 1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pickUpBananas);

function pickUpBananas(event:Event){

    for (var i:int = theBananas.length-1; i>-1; i--){

            if (sideMinion.hitTestObject(theBananas[i])){
                stage.removeChild(theBananas[i]);
                theBananas.splice(i,1);

        }
        else if (sideMinion.hitTestObject(theBananas[i])==false){
            health=health-10;
            healthPercent=health/100;
            trace(healthPercent);
            life.scaleX= healthPercent;

        }
    }
}

    }


stop();
```

And banana class:

```
    package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class banana extends MovieClip {

        var velX: Number = 0;
        var velY: Number = 0;
        var falling: Boolean = false;
        var gravity: Number = 2;

        public function banana() {
            var timing: Timer = new Timer(25, 0);
            timing.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveMe);
            timing.start();

        }

         private function moveMe(event: TimerEvent)
    {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        if (falling) velY += gravity;

       /* trace("[BANANA] position:", x, y, "speed:", velX, velY);*/
    }


        public function setSpeed(dx,dy) {
            velX = dx;
            velY = dy;
        }

            public function setSpot(atX,atY){
            this.x=atX;
            this.y=atY;
        }


        public function makeItFall (){
            falling=true;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically in the `else` block. You say if the banana hits, do x, `else` do y. That's the problem. You can keep your first part `if banana hits the minion, do x` and then add `if banana hits bottom do y`.

Get rid of the `else`.

Hope that made sense.

Edit:

```
if (the banana is hitting the minion){
    // add health or whatever
    // remove banana from array
    return;
}
if (the banana hits the floor){
    // lose health or whatever
    // remove banana from array
    return;
}
```

The return statement is so that if you remove a banana, you exit that function instead of going on to the next if statement and checking for a banana that has already been removed.

Comment: The problem is that in the same line I am getting two syntax errors which don't even make sense. Line 85 column 51 expecting identifiers before equal and column 102 expecting semicolon before right parenthesis.

Comment: The line is 85 (the line with the else statement).

Comment: Perfect :) Part of the  problem was that I was still keeping the && in the statement. Thank you.